# Beating Interference on Digital Piano

Tags: digital-piano

When I press C3 key alone on the digital piano (Roland), and let the sound sustain until fading out. I hear the inconsistent volume (wobble) on the single note.

Q: Is this incident considered as the beating frequency between the strings on the single note on the acoustic piano? If not what causes this to happen?

Comment: See also: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32395/digital-piano-adjacent-notes-make-wavering-wobble-sound-when-played-together?rq=1

Comment: So, that means the acoustic piano can have the beating frequency on a unison? Isn’t it supposed to be perfectly in tune for a piano unison?

Comment: See e.g. this answer: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/83005/in-one-note-played-on-a-piano-say-c4-what-can-we-say-about-the-phases-of-the-d/83010#83010

Comment: What’s the specific model of the Roland?

Comment: Acoustic pianos strings are not tuned in perfect unison. This is a normal part of the sound of a piano the Roland has recreated.

Comment: @trw The model is Roland F-120

Comment: @ToddWilcox That is immensely knowledgable!!

Comment: @YourUncleBob This is so helpful.